# Where are received mails by Mailcatcher stored?

Tags: mailcatcher

I have installed postfix on my Mac with and changed the following parameters :

```
mydestination =
relayhost = 127.0.0.1:1025
```

I've modified *mydestination* to be blank so that whoever the mail is sent to like bellow in the Terminal it necessarily goes through the relayhost (even if it's sent to @localhost) and I can see it appear in my web-browser in Mailcatcher's tab :

```
echo "Body test" | mail -s "Subject test" test@dev.local
```

But here's the thing, when I receive the mail I do receive it instantly with the built-in websockets but if I do reload the page localhost:1080, emails are still there, meaning they must be stored somewhere.

After searching I found that the following URL redirects to a .json that contains received mails that are print out in Mailcatcher's tab :

```
localhost:1080/messages
```

But if I do a `ls -l` in my webroot directory, there's no messages.json that appears. And when you do click on the "Quit" button in Mailcatcher's, then relaunch it by doing `mailcatcher` and opening again `localhost:1080` mails have disappeared...

I don't understand, is there a file that is deleted when you do click "Quit" and that I might haven't seen ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

If you check the source on GitHub you will find something like this `SQLite3::Database.new(":memory:", :type_translation => true).tap do |db|` in **mail.rb**.

You may not have noticed, but MailCatcher uses SQLite, and the above tells you that it is configured to run in memory. So, when turning off MailCatcher all the rows that are contained in this database are lost.